# request.Form[control id] getting null after submit button click

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My html controls in my view are bound to my view Model properties
like so:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    m => m.SelectedServiceLine, 
    Model.ServiceList, 
    new { id = "Service", multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 150px;" })
```

I am fetching the selected value using `request.Form[Service]` and passing it as a parameter to my procedure when clicking submit but when I change my values and submit I am not able to retrieve value in `request.Form[Service]` as I am getting `null` here.
Note: during rebind after clicking the submit button the value in `SelectedServiceLine` is taken from `request.Form[Service]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key used in post is the name of the control, not the id.

To get the value of this control:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedServiceLine, Model.ServiceList, new { id = "Service", multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 150px;" })
```

you should use

```
Request.Form["SelectedServiceLine"]
```

Comment: Thanks Diego! that was really helpful Cheers!